# Scrollable PagerTabStrip

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've been searching for this topic for a while, and can't find enough resources or tuts about scrolling a `PagerTabStrip`. I'm using the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and populates the `PagerTabStrip` with `getPageTitle(int position)`. I'd like to know how to make the `titles` scrollable. I'd like to scroll the titles without affecting the view by the time I stop or select into a specific title, then that's the time the view gets updated. I've been thinking to use `HorizontialListView` but not sure how to start. Hoping to learn from you. Thanks.

Found this on docu:

> PagerTabStrip is an interactive indicator of the current, next, and
>   previous pages of a ViewPager. It is intended to be used as a child
>   view of a ViewPager widget in your XML layout. Add it as a child of a
>   ViewPager in your layout file and set its android:layout_gravity to
>   TOP or BOTTOM to pin it to the top or bottom of the ViewPager. The
>   title from each page is supplied by the method getPageTitle(int) in
>   the adapter supplied to the ViewPager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I been searching on this on the web, but I didn't get any relevant resources. I just found out another library called actionsherlock that enables the scrolling of tabs without affecting the view which is exactly what I need, instead of using  `PagerTabStrip`'s listener .

Answer (score 0):

I'm also searching for the same thing. Too bad you have to make your own implementation or use third-party library. I have read that this library offer the feature of scrolling tab independent of the content. But I have not tried it out yet.

http://viewpagerindicator.com/?utm_source=androidweekly&utm_medium=toolbox

Do you actually mean the ActionBarSherlock? Do you have an example?